# Problems installing Samba on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install

Tags: networking, server, samba

Set up a new server. I installed a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, ran a standard software update, and installed a video driver. That is all I've done. Now I'm simply trying to install Samba onto the system.

So I do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Updates and upgrades runs fine. It's on the install that I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  samba-libs

E: Package 'samba' has no installation candidate
```

I feel like I've installed Samba a decent amount of times and have never seen this error. Can someone explain what is going on and how to address it?

Edit: As per request in the comments, the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` are as follows:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: The package `samba` version 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.11 is currently in the 18.04 main repo. I suggest you [edit] your question and include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` since there appears to be an issue with that.  When I type `sudo apt install samba -s` I get a normal feedback. (The -s is because I don't actually want to install it)

Comment: @Organic Marble, ok, I've added the contents of that file. What do you think?

Comment: I see a problem, will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why, but your sources.list is missing the `main` repo.

The first uncommented line

`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic restricted`

should read

`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted`

Somehow you have removed this important repo from your sources.  It appears to be gone from all the other lines as well.  (I note that it appears in the commented out lines).

Here is a stock sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

Comment: So strange. Any guess as to how this happened? I literally just did a fresh install from the most current 18.04 LTS (18.04.3), installed a video driver, and ran the software update. That's it.

Comment: It is difficult for me to compare because I have a local mirror so my sources list and the guis for it look nothing like the stock one. If forced to guess I would say you inadvertently unchecked something on the software and updates page.

Comment: Since it appears in the comments, I'm forced to conclude that it was there originally.

Comment: I'm going to do a fresh install and go through the process all over again just because I want to see where I went wrong. At least I know how to address it now if it appears again.

Comment: Since I did show what caused your problem, please consider upvoting my answer.

Comment: I absolutely did. It says since I do not have a reputation of 15 or above, it will be recorded, but not shown publicly. Thank you so much.